# Number of six digit numbers which are divisible by $6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question is to find out the number of six digit numbers that can be formed using only the digits $2,3,9$ which are divisible by $6$

---

For a number to be divisible by $6$ it must be divisible by both $2$ and $3$ .For being divisible by $2$ last digit of the number should be $2$.Hence the question is all about finding out the number of non negative integral solution of equation $$3a+2b+9c=3k-2$$ for some positive $k$ under the constraint $a+b+c=5$.I couldn't proceed after this since it becomes difficult to deal with $k$.Any ideas?Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could just ask a computer to do it for you. There are only 729 six-digit numbers made of 2s, 3s, and 9s, it can't take too long for a machine to generate them all and count how many are multiples of six. Or, you could note that the equation you wrote down forces $2b+2$ to be a multiple of 3, which forces $b$ to be 2 or 5, which cuts down on the work considerably.

Comment: @GerryMyerson this is a exam question.no calculators were permitted

Comment: OK, is there any other important information you've left out?

Comment: @GerryMyerson no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire number modulo 3 is the same as as the *sum of digits* modulo 3. Since only one of the digits is nonzero modulo 3 -- namely $2$ -- the number of 2s in the number must be either 0, 3 or 6. The first of these is impossible (because you know the *last* digit is 2), so we have

- The single number $222222$
- Numbers with exactly three 2s, of which one comes last. There are $\binom 52 \cdot 2^3$ of these (why?).

Answer (score 5):

The number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$.  So if you have a $2$, you must have three $2$'s.  If you have four $2$'s then you must have six.  So one number is $222,222$.  All others must have three digits of $3$ or $9$ and then three $2$'s and end with $2$.

So first there are $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ ways to choose the non-$2$ digits.  Each of those is either $3$ or $9$, so there are $8$ ways to fill in the non-$2$ digits for each of the $10$ patterns.  So that's $80$.  Add the $222,222$ case and the answer is $81$.